# How to use beautifulsoup to save html of a link in a file and do the same with all the links in the html file

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to write a parser which will take a url and download it's html in a .html file. Then it'll go through the html file to find all links and save them as well. I want to repeat it multiple time. Can some one please help a little?

This is the code I have written:

```
import requests
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link_set = set()
count = 1
give_url = raw_input("Enter url:\t")


def magic(give_url):
    page = urllib2.urlopen(give_url)

    page_content = page.read()

    with open('page_content.html', 'w') as fid:
        fid.write(page_content)


    response = requests.get(give_url)
    html_data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data)

    list_items = soup.find_all('a')

    for each_item in list_items:
        html_link = each_item.get('href')
        link_set.add(give_url + str(html_link))

magic(give_url)

for each_item in link_set:
    print each_item
    print "\n"
```

Although it's working fine but When I try to call the `magic` function in for loop, i get `RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration`.

Comment: Where is your current code?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the code here. I didn't know I had to paste the code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.
The code for recursive URL parsing using beautiful soup:

```
import requests
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link_set = set()
give_url = raw_input("Enter url:\t")

def magic(give_url, link_set, count):
    # print "______________________________________________________"
    #
    # print "Count is: " + str(count)
    # count += 1
    # print "THE URL IT IS SCRAPPING IS:" + give_url
    page = urllib2.urlopen(give_url)

    page_content = page.read()

    with open('page_content.html', 'w') as fid:
        fid.write(page_content)


    response = requests.get(give_url)
    html_data = response.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data)

    list_items = soup.find_all('a')

    for each_item in list_items:
        html_link = each_item.get('href')
        if(html_link is None):
            pass
        else:
            if(not (html_link.startswith('http') or  html_link.startswith('https'))):
                link_set.add(give_url + html_link)
            else:
                link_set.add(html_link)

    # print "Total links in the given url are:  " + str(len(link_set))


magic(give_url,link_set,0)

link_set2 = set()
link_set3 = set()

for element in link_set:
    link_set2.add(element)

count = 1
for element in link_set:
    magic(element,link_set3,count)
    count += 1
    for each_item in link_set3:
        link_set2.add(each_item)
    link_set3.clear()

count = 1
print "Total links scraped are: " + str(len(link_set2))
for element in link_set2:
    count +=1
    print "Element number " + str(count) + "processing"
    print element
    print "\n"
```

There are many mistakes so I request you all to please tell me where I can improve the code.